# Calculating total amount of row from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to calculate the total amount of all the prices I get from my database but I can't figure it out. Its a bill from a restaurant.

```
$parameters = array(':tafelnummer'=>$tafelnummer);

$sth = $pdo->prepare("select * from bestellingen WHERE Tafelnummer = '$tafelnummer'");
$sth->execute();




while($row = $sth->fetch())
{
    
    
    echo "<tr> ";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td>" . $row['Soort'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td> " . $row['Price'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr> "; 
    

}
```

The price wil give a result for each dish which I need a total amount for

Comment: I haven't calculated the total of Price anywere. I was looking all over the web trying to figure it out but haven't found the solution for my code

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than going back to the database, you can keep an accumulator and then add a TOTAL line to the bill.

Also I have attempted to fix your SQL Injection issue.

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare("select * from bestellingen WHERE Tafelnummer = :tn");
$sth->execute([':tn' => $tafelnummer]);

$tot = 0;

while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
        
    echo "<tr> ";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td>" . $row['Soort'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td> " . $row['Price'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr> "; 

    $tot += (float)$row['Price'];
}

echo "<tr> ";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td><td>TOTAL</td><td>$tot</td>";
echo "</tr> ";
```

Comment: I tried your code, it gave me this result. I made a link to a screen capture so you can view the result better: https://ibb.co/WcFRRP2 Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The letters are gone now but it still showed me the result 2.5 which is not the total amount of all the prices (see image)

Comment: Changed the `$tot += (float)$row['Price'];` to cast the text to float,

Comment: https://ibb.co/0mCvqb7 Its in the correct position like this, but it does not count all the prices. Did I forget something? --> to anwser ur latest question, the prices are stored as decimals.

Comment: Very strange. Are you SURE that the `$tot=0` is OUTSIDE the loop. Before you run the while loop

Comment: Yes, 100% sure that its outside of the while loop

Comment: I added a debug line can you show the output from that code please

Comment: Ok, what changed that you suddenly accepted the answer ??

Comment: I found the problem, sorry for the trouble. I placed it at the code that gives results for only the drinks and not the dishes. I placed it correctly now and it works perfect. Really really thankful for your help

Comment: I placed this code only at the part for the drinks, not the dishes. I had to place it there and combine the two variable together

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(Price) AS Totalamount 
FROM bestellingen 
WHERE Tafelnummer = '$tafelnummer'
```

use this query than get the Totalamount.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can I also use this in a php file and show the result on my screen?

Comment: $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(Price) AS Totalamount 
FROM bestellingen 
WHERE Tafelnummer = '$tafelnummer'");
$sth->execute();

$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$sum = $row['Totalamount'];

Answer (score 0):

Just use a variable $total and add each price into it in the while loop.

```
$total=0;

while($row = $sth->fetch())
{
    $total+=(int)$row["Price"];
    echo "<tr> ";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>"; 
      echo "<td>" . $row['Soort'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td> " . $row['Price'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr> "; 
}
```

Make sure your Price value is always integer. It is not necessary to typecast to (int).

Comment: Prices are almost never integers since Italy joined the Euro :)